# I cannot connect the mysql database to my asp.net mvc project

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to connect the mysql database to my asp.net mvc project using ado.net. So far everything is going well. When I test it, I am not getting problems. But when I click "next", the window closes and the first adding window opens again.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the old Entity Framework? Why not use Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Did you install [Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) on your development system?